# How to toggle Chrome to full screen automatically

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to toggle chrome to full screen automatically, but it does not work, here is the sample code

```
<html>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<div>Full Screen Test</div>
<input id="fullScreentButton" type="button" value="toggle" onclick="enterFullScreen()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    //enter the fullscreen on click, works.
    function enterFullScreen(){
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
    function enterFullScreenInJquery(){
        $('#fullScreentButton').trigger('click');
    }
    //enter the fullscreen on startup, does not work
    enterFullScreenInJquery();
</script>
```

If I click the button, it works, how come the jquery one does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fullscreen JavaScript API only works during user interaction, so it cannot be used maliciously.

Comment: E.g., in response to a user event, like the user actually clicking the button. The fullscreen spec says it has to [be allowed to show a popup](http://www.w3.org/TR/fullscreen/#api), and the nearest thing to a spec on that [says popups are only allowed when processing a user event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup).

Comment: So, chrome actually knows if I'm really clicking the mouse or simulating?